# SwiftUI - Update variable in ForEach Loop to alternate background color of a list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I tried to implement a pingpong variable for a list so I could alternate the background color. For some reason the below throws and error but the compiler just says "Failed to Build." When I remove the "switchBit" function call from within the view, it compiles fine. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

```
struct HomeScreen: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.green,.white]
    @State var pingPong: Int = 0

    var body: some View {


        NavigationView{
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(jobPostingData){jobposting in

                             NavigationLink(destination: jobPostingPage()) {
                                JobListingsRow(jobposting: jobposting).foregroundColor(Color.black).background(self.colors[self.pingPong])


                            }

                            self.switchBit()
                        }

                    }
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                }
            }

            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Current Listed Positons"))
        }

    }

    func switchBit() {
        self.pingPong = (self.pingPong == 1) ? 0 : 1
    }

}
```

Comment: You can not call function just inside the body. You can use conditions in your view modifieres or in view lifecycles events. Amrit showed a perfect answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want alternate coloraturas for the rows. You will have to avoid the switchBit code and use something like below to switch colours:

```
struct Homescreen: View {
  let colors: [Color] = [.green,.white]
  @State var jobPostingData: [String] = ["1","2", "3","4"]
  @State var pingPong: Int = 0

  var body: some View {


    NavigationView{
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(self.jobPostingData.indices, id: \.self) { index in

                        JobListingsRow(jobposting: self.jobPostingData[index])
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            .background(index % 2 == 0 ? Color.green : Color.red)

                    }

                }

                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            }
        }

        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Current Listed Positons"))
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks! So SwiftUI doesn’t let you update variables inside a view multiple times? I managed to get my code working so it would flip 1 time but that was all.